# The following python 3.6.x code fails on Atom but not on IDLE

Tags: python-3.x

DISCLAIMER: I'm a new Python programmer (a few hours into a beginner course)

I created a slicer example on Python's 3.6.3 IDLE and it ran as supposed to. Here it is:

```
*email = input("What's your email address ? ").strip()
user = email[:email.find("@")]
user = user.capitalize()
domain = email[email.find("@") + 1:]
domain = domain.capitalize()
output = "Your username is {} and your domain is {}".format(user,domain)
print(output)*
```

However, when attempting to run it in Atom, the script-runner package gives me the following error:

```
*What's your email address ? user1@gmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/**user**/Desktop/Scripts/MyPyScripts/slicer.py", line 9, in <module>
    email = input("What's your email address ? ").strip()
  File "<string>", line 1
    user1@gmail.com*
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Exited with status 1 after 10.893 seconds
```

Would anyone have an idea? Thanks kindly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Atom is using Python 2.x, not 3.x.  `input` on Python 2 evaluates the string entered, e.g. the string `2+3` returns `5`.  Use `raw_input` on Python 2 to just read a string without evaluation.

```
>>> input('enter email: ')
enter email: test@gmail.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    test@gmail.com
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> raw_input('enter email: ')
enter email: test@gmail.com
'test@gmail.com'
```